# How to draw image in WebGL using another canvas buffer Data?

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl

I am trying to draw image to webgl canvas from a 2d canvas.

If I use:

```
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
```

, it works and renders the image successfully, but if I use :

```
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0,  gl.RGBA, c.width, c.height, 0,  gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, dataTypedArray);
```

, it just shows a black screen.

Here's my Code :

**Vertex Shader**

```
attribute vec2 a_position;
uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform mat3 u_matrix;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(u_matrix * vec3(a_position, 1), 1);
    v_texCoord = a_position;
}
```

**Fragment Shader**

```
precision mediump float;
// our texture
uniform sampler2D u_image;
// the texCoords passed in from the vertex shader.
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord);
}
```

**Javascript**

```
window.onload = main;
var buffer = null;
function main() {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "images/GL.jpg"
    image.onload = function() {
        render(image);
    }
}

function render(image) {
    var c = document.getElementById("c");
    c.width = window.innerWidth*0.90;
    c.height = window.innerHeight*0.90;
    var context = c.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

    var imageData = context.getImageData(0,0,image.width,image.height);
    buffer = imageData.data.buffer;  // ArrayBuffer
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth*0.90;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight*0.90;

    //Get A WebGL context
    var gl = getWebGLContext(canvas);
    if (!gl) {
        return;
    }

    // setup GLSL program
    var program = createProgramFromScripts(gl, ["2d-vertex-shader", "2d-fragment-shader"]);
    gl.useProgram(program);

    // look up where the vertex data needs to go.
    var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position"); 

    // look up uniform locations
    var u_imageLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_image");
    var u_matrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_matrix");

    // provide texture coordinates for the rectangle.
    var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
           0.0,  0.0,
           1.0,  0.0,
           0.0,  1.0,
           0.0,  1.0,
           1.0,  0.0,
           1.0,  1.0]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    var texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    // Set the parameters so we can render any size image.
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

    // Upload the image into the texture.
    var dataTypedArray = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    //gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    textureFromPixelArray(gl, buffer, gl.RGBA, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    var dstX = 20;
    var dstY = 30;
    var dstWidth = canvas.width;
    var dstHeight = canvas.height;

    // convert dst pixel coords to clipspace coords      
    var clipX = dstX / gl.canvas.width  *  2 - 1;
    var clipY = dstY / gl.canvas.height * -2 + 1;
    var clipWidth = dstWidth  / gl.canvas.width  *  2;
    var clipHeight = dstHeight / gl.canvas.height * -2;

    // build a matrix that will stretch our
    // unit quad to our desired size and location
    gl.uniformMatrix3fv(u_matrixLoc, false, [
        clipWidth, 0, 0,
        0, clipHeight, 0,
        clipX, clipY, 1,
        ]);

    // Draw the rectangle.
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
}


 function textureFromPixelArray(gl, dataArray, type, width, height)        {
      var dataTypedArray = new Uint8Array(dataArray); // Don't need to do this if the data is already in a typed array
      var texture = gl.createTexture();
      gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
      gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, type, width, height, 0, type, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, dataTypedArray);
      // Other texture setup here, like filter modes and mipmap generation
      console.log(dataTypedArray);
      return texture;
  }
```

Comment: How does dataTypedArray look like? Post it here.

Comment: For me, the sizes of the image look strange. You read [image.width, image.height] texels from the context into image data, but then tell gl that the image has a size of [canvas.width, canvas.height].

Comment: How about passing `dataTypedArray` into your `textureFromPixelArray` method. As of now `dataTypedArray` is local to your `render` method thus not visible within `textureFromPixelArray`. In non strict mode this will result in `undefined` being passed which will make texImage2D fill the texture with black.

Comment: No I have now got the answer , Actually I was not using correct height and width, BDL's comment is correct above. Thanks

Comment: Ah sorry, now I see.

Answer (score 1):

So first off, you can pass a canvas directly to `gl.texImage2D`. There's no good reason to first call `ctx.getImageData` and get the data out. Just call

```
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, someCanvas);
```

Second, looking at your code you first create a texture, then set filtering. You then call `textureFromPixelArray`, **WHICH CREATES A NEW TEXTURE**, that texture does not have filtering set so if it's not a power-of-2 then it won't render. Just a guess but did you check the JavaScript console? I'm just guessing it probably printed a warning about your texture not being renderable.

On top of that, even though `textureFromPixelArray` creates a new texture the code ignores the return value.

To make the code work as is I think you want to change it to this

```
// not needed -- var texture = gl.createTexture();
// not needed --  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

// moved from below
// Upload the image into the texture.
var dataTypedArray = new Uint8Array(buffer);
//gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
var texture = textureFromPixelArray(gl, buffer, gl.RGBA, canvas.width, canvas.height);

// Set the parameters so we can render any size image.
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
```